# Converting a generated keypair into a base58 or seed phrase?

Tags: keypair, address

I did the following in my html file in the chrome console. After I get the following public and private keypair. How do I convert it into a base58 or seed phrase?

The docs below don't state how to go about it:

https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase

[image]

Comment: Are you following a guide? You can not go from a keypair to a mnemonic.

Comment: it is unclear what the screenshot is representing.  ed25519 private (secret) keys are 32-bytes, but this claims to be 64.  either way, if there are any assets controlled by that keypair, they should be moved to a new wallet and this keypair destroyed. private means private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For converting your Public Key into `base58`, look at [this](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#toBase58) reference.

Also, it is not possible to generate a mnemonic from a Keypair.

However, the vice-versa is true, as highlighted in the docs you linked.

Comment: Good answer, teach 'em to fish!

Answer (score 1):

```
const keypair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.generate();
const base58 = keypair.publicKey().toBase58();
```

Comment: I'm getting: publicKey is not a function -- Was I suppose to add more libraries to make this work? I only have solana web3.js